# Toast at application start

Tags: android, toast

How do I trigger toast notification at application start time?

Comment: Welcome to SO! For help, you should post your attempt at the problem and clearly explain the problem. So far, it doesn't look like you have attempted to solve your problem

Comment: why you change my question????

Comment: I believe Xiao was trying to make your question more understandable and I think it worked. Apparently, so did 3 other people since the suggested edit was accepted.

Comment: if2 is aggressive boy. Please don't dare to touch his question :D

Comment: i'm sorry, I still do not understand the rules here because I am a beginner :D
Thank's all ;)

Comment: @if2 Don't take downvotes or edits too personally. When that happens, it's usually to teach you how to use the site more efficiently and to keep it clean.

Answer (score 2):

Add the toast into the onCreate Method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toast.makeText(this, "This is my Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: why -1? at least respond!

Comment: it wasnt me but that made me laugh and i upped you

Comment: =) hihihi :D, some users are newbies and we must effort to understand and help!

Comment: I didn't downvote but, IMHO, answering questions which show no effort encourage bad behavior on this site. Also, this would run every time the `Activity` ran and not "when the application is first run". **Side-note:** I did like the `Toast` before the rollback

Comment: thank's elenasys, it's work for me ^_^

Comment: you're welcome, as codeMagicpoints out, "post your attempt at the problem and clearly explain the problem", so we can help you faster!=)

Comment: New programmers need encouragement, see how much happy if2 is on a little help :)